# Do gravitational wave produce varying electromagnetic waves?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, gravitational-waves

When gravitational waves produce electromagnetic waves, do they produce them of the same frequency or of varying wavelength?

Comment: I'm describing if gravitational waves could (theoretically)  interfere  (no  matter  how small) with our wireless communications.

Comment: Suggest you drop reference to a project. This makes your question sound naive and will lead to more downvotes.

Comment: Consider it done.

Comment: How do gravitational waves produce electromagnetic waves?

Answer (score 1):

Gravitational waves do not produce electromagnetic waves, but they can affect them. Gravitational waves distort space-time and if electromagnetic waves are propagating through the same space-time region  the EM wave will be likewise distorted. The effect will be minuscule as the LIGO experiments demonstrate.  Gravitational red shift although not associated with gravitational waves is another example of gravity affecting EM waves.